# How can I sort a pivot table sort by multiple columns?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

Hey stackoverflow community,

Looking to find a solution for a pretty simple problem (I think). In a normal Excel dataset, one can sort with many different options. If you go to `Data -> Sort`, you can add multiple levels of sorting, i.e. "I want to sort by revenue, then total quantity, then alphabetic Product order, etc."

When in pivot table sorting, even if you only have one Row column (say Product), you cannot sort by multiple columns in values. So by product, I could not sort by Total Quantity descending, then Revenue descending.

The data needs to stay in pivot table format. Thanks all!

Answer (score -4):

Set custom sort options. To sort specific items manually or change the sort order, you can set your own sort options. Click a field in the row or column you want to sort. Click the arrow on Row Labels or Column Labels, and then click More Sort Options.